# keep track of the smallest and the lagest number so far

Tags: c++

i'm trying to make a programme that's take one input within a loop and keep track of the smallest and largest seen so far.
i write the code but i don't know whats wrong with it, this is the code:

```
    double val = 0;
    double smaller = 0;
    double larger = 0;
    while(cin >> val){
        cout << val << '\n';
        if(val >= larger){
                larger = val;
                cout << "the larger so far\n";
        }
        else if(val <= smaller){
                smaller = val;
                cout << "the smaller so far\n";
        }
        else
            cout << "in between\n";
```

and this is the output;

```
23
23
the larger so far
1
1
WTF
234
234
the larger so far
23
23
WTF
0
0
the smaller so far
```

Comment: You need to initialise `smaller`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You initialize `smaller` with zero, but if you receive a number that is larger than 0 but still is the smallest of the input, the `smaller` variable will not be updated.

The same problem will appear with the `larger` value if all of the numbers are negative (e.g. if the input is `-1; -3`, `larger` will not be updated).

There are two ways of solving this problem.

1. Initialize `smaller` with a value that is *guaranteed* to be smaller than all of the input and `larger` with a value *guaranteed* to be greater than all of the input.
2. Initialize both `smaller` and `larger` with the first input number.

Answer (score 3):

```
double smaller, larger = 0;
```

This is the equivalent of:

```
double smaller;
double larger = 0;
```

And not of, as you might've thought:

```
double smaller = 0;
double larger = 0;
```

Which means you're leaving `smaller` uninitialized when you start using it, causing undefined behavior.

Comment: This issue is a good reason to declare one variable per line.

Comment: thanks for replying,  i edit it but still the same problem

Comment: @kionagi You know what my crystal ball says? You probably set it to 0 (note that the answer doesn't suggest that), instead of an arbitrary large value, preferably `std::numeric_limits<int>::max()`.

Answer (score 0):

here i solve the problem :

```
    double val = 0;
    double smaller = std::numeric_limits<double>::max();
    double larger = std::numeric_limits<double>::min();
    while(cin >> val){
        cout << val << '\n';
        if(val >= larger){
                larger = val;
                cout << "the larger so far\n";
        }
        else if(val <= smaller){
                smaller = val;
                cout << "the smaller so far\n";
        }
        else
            cout << "in between\n";
```